# What does 'mindwarp' mean here?

Tags: meaning

The 'Black Mirror' Christmas Special Is A Total `Mindwarp`, According To Twitter.

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2014/12/26/black-mirror-christmas-twitter_n_6382820.html?utm_hp_ref=tw

What does `mindwarp` mean here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mindwarp can really only be understood by deconstructing the word and from context.

"Mind" is clear enough, and "warp" literally means to bend.  Here we're using its figurative meaning, to disturb or pervert something otherwise wholesome.

I haven't seen this show (though I plan to, now that I know it exists) but it is apparently a surreal/horror series.  This particular episode, the Christmas special, is a mindwarp because it will twist your mind in unexpected and uncomfortable ways.  It has perverted something wholesome (Christmas) into something emotionally disturbing.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now! Just wondering, in your answer, can we just say `something wholesome` rather than `something otherwise wholesome`

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo Yes, that change would be fine.

Comment: Just wondering, by adding the word `otherwise`, is there any difference (even slight one)?